# Stumped. (C#, JSP)

Tags: c#

So long story short, the company I work for, that is all about saving money, went from 1 service application, to 2 service web interfaces.
They're not secure, have no cert's, not even over SSL...yet, they have a timeout associated with each interface. Which then breaks the page you're viewing, and you have to refresh IE, and then proceed to login again, and reset your dropdowns etc...

So.

I've tried using a generic webbrowser interface in C# to have a foundation in which I can refresh the connection to the server with the page open, as to avert the timeout.
But, first attempt results in my app, going to the appropriate page, then opening a new IE window when a service ticket is opened, and there must be a lack of cached data, which results in the new IE window that opens, to revert back to the main page which prompts me to login.

The interfaces are Jsp, but I'm more familiar with c#...

Tried catching link clicks to navigate the destination in the current window, but it seems that the data you double click that prompts the new page to open, is merely a data in a table, and not technically a "link"....

I've brought this to the attention of management, but like most huge corporations, I know nothing, and they never have to deal with it, so as they say in every meeting, "silence means compliance"....

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

*Probably not the right answer, but...*

Session cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Session cookies = fail..
No 'remember me' option...

I can however enter a link in each browser to "goto the home" section of each app, which each page is already at, so it keeps the connection alive, and doesn't navigate away from the current page (keeping the dropdowns etc that are set after login)

But still, the above problem exists where if I use all this in a C# browser, etc...

I told my boss first thing 'they can't tell me the timeout is for security!' heh
And I still didn't get a positive answer from 'well at 10 seconds per re-logon, per x amount of people = thousands of dollars a year spent on re-logging on...'

:D

Comment: Please do not post comments/updates as answers. The messages are usually not ordered by insertion order and your message may get lost in noise. Instead use "add comment" link below the answer you'd like to comment on, or the "edit" link below the question you'd like to update.

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax.

- poll a server page in a small interval (a minute)
- if it returns "timeouted=true" (or whatever convention you like), [refresh the page](http://www.quackit.com/javascript/javascript_refresh_page.cfm) with javascript.
- include the ajax snippet on every page (using `<jsp:include>`, for example)

Comment: well I can't run the html's locally, and I'm not very familiar with ajax, how do you suggest I inject the refresh stuff? I do not have access to the server... heh well I might, but that's besides the point... just lookin to have this functionality on my pc, and anybody else that's annoyed by having to login over and over and over thru the day... :D

Comment: ajax is simple, in the simple case (like yours). You can use jQuery for taht. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770785/reverse-ajax-jsp-servlet

Comment: Interesting! Thanks very much, I think there may indeed be something adaptable in here! :)