# Invalidate a session on browser close using JSP/Servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

How can I invalidate a session on browser close using JSP/Servlets?

Comment: Hi, your question seems to be a duplicate. Have a look :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4713234/invalidate-a-session

Answer (score 3):

You `can't` do that. Set session's `timeout`, it will be automatically invlidated after a specific amount of time of inactivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that, but it seems like a bad thing to do.

Bind a function to the unload event of the window and make an ajax call to invalidate the session.

Using jQuery you might do this:

```
     $(window).unload(function()
        {
            alert("Yar, the light be fadin.");
        });
```

Of course, replace the alert with the ajax call you want to make.

Setting the session timeout seems like a better option.